# How to get numbers of shared item through facebook share button?

Tags: facebook, statistics, facebook-insights

I am using facebook's below code to share particular urls.

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={URL}.

I want to count which my url is most shared by user.

So how could I get the most shared urls? Is is possible to get such things?

for example:

I am sharing urls like

1) www.mysite.com/page1.html (shared 2 times)

2) www.mysite.com/page2.html (shared 5 times)

3) www.mysite.com/page3.html (shared 10 times)

Is it possible that i can get the counter of shared for each page?

Waiting for reply....

Thanks,

Niko.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below 2 way we can get counter :

```
1) http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.google.com

2) https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.google.com&format=json
```

First (1), will give total counter

Second (2), will return

- share_count,
- like_count,
- comment_count,
- total_count,
- click_count,
- comments_fbid,
- commentsbox_count

Answer (score 2):

This is possible through the Facebook api 
just use this

http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.google.com

and you will get

"id": "http://www.google.com",
   "shares": 9913603,
   "comments": 926